# Java JtextArea multiple letters

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have created a GUI that has number buttons(1-9) where if you click on 1 then the number 9, it will show 19 on the JtextArea. I am currently using

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        if(e.getSource() == buttons[i])
        textArea.(buttons[i].getText());
    }
```

when I click on the 9, it replaces what I already have on my textArea instead of adding it. Is there a different way I should do it so it will add them all up so i could have "192323" inputed by clicking on those instead of the last button i clicked so "3"?

Comment: How is `textArea.(buttons[i].getText());` compiling ?

Answer (score 3):

```
 textArea.append(buttons[i].getText());
```

Comment: Add a new line at the end it I would say it's perfect ;)

Comment: Exactly as it says, it will append the text to the end of the text area instead of replacing the text (like `setText` does)

Comment: Makes sense. How would I put a ENTER in there? so i will go down a line?

Comment: `textArea.append(buttons[i].getText() + "\n");`

Comment: or `textArea.append(buttons[i].getText() +System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Comment: `What does append mean or do?` - Did you read the API for a description?

Comment: @Apurv, Don't use the line.separator. Swing Documents only store "\n" in the Document so any other character will be filtered or replaced anyway.

Comment: If the point was to concatenate the numbers, the newline is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Append the required text

```
textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + buttons[i].getText());
```

Comment: Make you're life easier and simply use `textArea.append` ;)

Comment: Wasn't aware of `append`. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this?:

```
textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + buttons[i].getText());
```

Comment: If I do this, when I click on the number 1, it outputs "11" instead of 1 every time I click it

Comment: Make you're life easier and simply use `textArea.append` ;)